# Install php pdo db library in Amazon ec2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

i want to install the php (5.6) pdo db lib in ec2 instance, when i tried

```
sudo yum install php56-pdo-dblib
```

i am getting

```
No package php56-pdo-dblib available.
```

Please help

Thanks

Thanigaivelan

Answer (score 0):

php56-mysqlnd by default should support pdo.

Try installing that and see how that goes.

M$SQL = php56-mssql

The above is the default mssql driver for linux+php

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i want to connect sql server using php in linux server.

Comment: added the SQL server connector above

Answer (score 0):

Search for the package using yum:

```
yum search pdo*
```

When you get the list of pdo packages, use the package name listed to install the one you need:

```
yum install <package_name>
```